# parameter estimation in arima models

Tags: time-series, matlab

I want to estimate the parameter of ARIMA model over a given set.I have been doing this.

```
md1=arima(1,0,1);
fit=estimate(md1,iseries);
```

but it gives an error:

```
Undefined function or method 'arima' for input arguments of type
'double'.
```

Now, what should I do?

Comment: What Matlab are you using ? It seems like you have a old version.

Comment: i am using matlab 2011